# How to make Qt static build run without install vc_redist.x64.exe

Tags: qt, visual-c++, compilation

I want to build Qt 5.10.1 using MSVC2015, and without MSVC Runtime.
Followed http://amin-ahmadi.com/2016/09/22/how-to-build-qt-5-7-statically-using-msvc14-microsoft-visual-studio-2015/

1. Configure:

> configure -static -debug-and-release -prefix
>   "C:\Qt\5.10.1-static-msvc2015" -platform win32-msvc2015 -qt-zlib
>   -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -sql-sqlite -sql-odbc -no-openssl -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests

2. modified `src\qtbase\mkspecs\common\msvc-desktop.conf` change `-MD` to `-MT`.

No error during building, but if I don't install MSVC runtime when I run my program will get:

`api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll` missing.

How to make the MSVC static standalone like Mingw static build?

The output of compiling test program:

> cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline
>   -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -O2 -MT -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_MULTIMEDIA_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG

If I don't do step 2, the output will be `-MD`.

So Why the `-MT` (step 2) didn't work?

If you having any idea or guessing, Please comment.

**Update:**

1. Win10 64

No matter I add `-static-runtime` or not, both can run with without `vc_redist`

2. Win 7 32

Qt 5.10.1 compilation passed, but got `api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0.dll is missing` when executing the program.

Even I reinstall `vc_redist` still got the error...

Relate: [Why installed vc_redist still gives api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0.dll is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51296482/why-installed-vc-redist-still-gives-api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing)

Qt 5.11.1 compilation also passed, but got `C1083: 'QtCore/qglobal.h':No such file or directory` when building the program.

Answer (score 2):

Compiling Qt sources from Qt 5.5.0 you can pass `-static-runtime` argument to configure for static runtime.

[Changes 5.5.0:](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/dist/changes-5.5.0?h=5.6#n580)

> [Windows] Added -static-runtime option.

[Config Options:](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/config_help.txt#n159)

> -static-runtime ...... With -static, use static runtime [no] (Windows only)

Comment: Do I need also change `-MT`?

Comment: Thanks to some hard work from the Qt developers, you no longer have to do any hacks to get a static CRT working! The new -static-runtime option automatically configures the build to use the appropriate flags for a static CRT, e.g. /MT and/or /MTd. https://github.com/alberthdev/alberthdev-misc/wiki/Building-Qt-v5.6-Statically-on-Windows

Comment: I have added additional details about this option and when it was introduced.

Comment: Got unresolved symbol error, Looks like I need `nmake clean` first.

Comment: `C1083: 'QtCore/qglobal.h':No such file or directory` any idea about this?

Comment: It's not necessarily a framework dependency problem. It could be your project dependency problem. Have you tried compiling and running an empty project?

Comment: Thanks! looks like you are right, But when I tried an empty QML project...it crashed directly instead of gives that error.