# Why installed vc_redist still gives api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0.dll is missing

Tags: windows, visual-c++, vcredist

When I reinstall(uninstall & install again by the `program and features`) `vc_redist.x86` MSVC2015, execute my program got the error

> api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0.dll is missing

The program did work before I reinstall. There was no error during the installation. So what could be the problem? I am guessing the register did not set the runtime path properly or some other possible makes program can't find the path.

Windows 7 32bit

Comment: @HansPassant It shows already installed KB2999226

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I write the wrong error message, I updated the question.

Comment: @HansPassant I uninstall the `vc_redist` by `program and features`